# Embed a glyphicon-ok in li

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to embed glyphicon-ok in `<li>` tag. Previously I tried to add content field in `nav-tabs.nav-justified > li`; but that didn't help:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 left_menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a>                        
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Icon is coming now, but I want to have a colored background before and after this icon. Any pointers?

Or is there any way to add content in `<li>` tag?

[image]

[image: New Image]

Comment: Have you tried using an <i> tag? As far as I know, they are meant to be used when displaying a glyphicon.

Comment: @Vasseurth : but i am the same problem again.. How can i put background color before glyphicon?

Comment: what do you mean by "before" icon? Can you show an example?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor : updated the code and have uploaded the image.. glyphicon is coming; but I need to put some background color before and after that. Something like the new Image (green color) with rounded corners.